# MacOS: Start new instance of TeXstudio

Tags: texstudio, mac

[MacOS 10.13.3, TeXstudio 2.12.8]

How do you start a new TeXstudio instance?

`open /Applications/texstudio.app --start-always` is not recognised and returns the *Usage* information, whilst `open /Applications/texstudio.app -n` does not create a new instance as the help information states and instead simply flashes the MacOS Menu Bar.

I tried copying the `texstudio.app` to another name and running it, but it didn't create a new instance either.  Is this possible?

Comment: just noticed that this is pretty much the same question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/426487/open-several-instances-of-texstudio?rq=1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To start a new instance:

```
/Applications/texstudio.app/Contents/MacOS/texstudio --start-always
```

(without open and with the full path to the binary)

Answer (score 5):

The right terminal command is `/Applications/texstudio.app/Contents/MacOS/texstudio --start-always`, but you will need to keep the terminal open.

---

You can create an application with Automator (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46995543/4550784) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17242773/pass-in-variable-from-shell-script-to-applescript#17243326)) to start new instances every time:

1. open **Automator** and create a new **Application** [image: menu]
2. to add `Run Shell Script` **drag and drop** it from the list; might need these settings `Shell: /bin/bash` and `Pass input: as arguments` [image: run shell script]
3. **insert the code below**; if necessary adjust the path to your TeXstudio executable

### Code

```
nohup /Applications/texstudio.app/Contents/MacOS/texstudio --start-always > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

4. **save** the script as an **application** (!)

You can now place this into your application folder.

### note

If you have a look at the [jupyter-version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46995543/4550784), you might think it could also work when opening files. However, I have not yet tried to re-associate files with this script in order to open a new instance for every file (since you can open other files as usual, e.g. drag and drop). This would also need some logic to differentiate between plain calls and calls with file-paths passed, I guess.