# TeXstudio - Open other instances / sessions on Windows

Tags: texstudio, windows, editors

> How can a second or more instances of TexStudio be opened on Windows?

A good answer for Linux can be found [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/426487/open-several-instances-of-texstudio)

**Context**

I'm reviewing my thesis and preparing a presentation, both using TexStudio for Windows. Would be really nice if I could have one window for each,such that if a correction must be made on the thesis (which takes long to compile) I can work on the presentation in the meantime. Opening TextStudio by clicking an icon does nothing. Trying to launch a `.tex` file opens it in the same instance of TexStudio.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You had the answer just not clearly the correct one, here are two windows at the same time that you should have got.

[image]

The key is your shortcut "Target" for the second instance should be

```
"whatever path to TeX studio\texstudio-2.12.14\texstudio.exe" --start-always
```

That is the unfamiliar double -- prefix at the start.

There are many places you may have a shortcut to start TeXstudio e.g. Start menu, taskbar, desktop or in my case a batch file.

The easiest way to keep an alternative in windows is create a copy from your existing start icon by right click and follow the link to existing folder or file location (usually where TeXstudio is located) then for that main item (shortcut or exe) right-click then `send to` > `Desktop (create shortcut)`

Right-click the properties of your duplicate desktop start-up (rename it on the `General` Tab) and in the `target` box go to the end and add a space then `--start-always`  similar to the example above.

The full range of options are currently listed here as [◦4.11 Synopsis of the TeXstudio command](http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/manual/current/usermanual_en.html#SECTION38)

For other ways to run dual compile using split editor and viewers see
https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/472480/170109 (split editor) and
https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/471069/170109 (split viewers)  https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/472806/170109 (split editor and viewers)

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't exactly answer your question, but one option is to open both files in one instance of TeXstudio and then split screen the documents within that single instance. You can right click on on of the document tabs and select "Move to other view".

Comment: That's helpful when copying-pasting things from one file to another (which I'm doing often), but indeed does not allow me to compile two files simultaneously.